# Checking if two dates are within 15 minutes of each other

Tags: c#, datetime

The following code compares two dates and checks if they are within 15 minutes of each other, with a tolerance of a second. All of the test cases below pass with the existing solution. The question is can it be improved by making it more efficient and/or elegant given the following test cases.

```
TestId, whenCreated, whenToCompareTo, expected Outcome

[(1, "01/01/2017 15:00:00", "01/01/2017 15:15:00", true)]
[(2, "01/01/2017 15:00:00", "01/01/2017 15:00:00", true)]
[(3, "01/01/2017 15:00:00", "01/01/2017 15:16:00", false)]
[(4, "01/01/2017 15:00:00", "01/01/2017 14:59:59", false)]
[(5, "01/01/2017 15:00:00", "01/01/2017 15:14:59", true)]
[(6, "01/01/2017 15:00:00", "01/01/2017 15:16:01", false)]
[(7, "2017-01-01T15:00:00.0000001", "2017-01-01T15:15:00.0000002", true)]
[(8, "2017-01-01T15:15:00.5170000", "2017-01-01T15:15:00.4537587", true)]
[(9, "2017-01-01 15:00:00", "2017-12-31 15:00:00", false)]
[(10, "2018-05-06T13:30:43.2200000", "2018-05-06T13:30:42.9978916", true)]
```

And here is the code that is doing the comparison:

```
public bool IsTokenAlive(DateTime timeToCompareTo)
{
    var isDateEarlier = DateComparison(timeToCompareTo, Created);
    var isCompareTimeOfDayEarlier = DateTimeOfDayComparison(timeToCompareTo, Created);
    var isExpired = AbsoluteSecondsComparison(timeToCompareTo, Created);
    var isAlive = isDateEarlier && (isCompareTimeOfDayEarlier || GetTotalSeconds(timeToCompareTo, Created) < 1) && isExpired;

    return isAlive;
}

private static bool DateComparison(DateTime timeToCompareTo, DateTime created)
{
    return DateTime.Compare(timeToCompareTo.Date, created.Date) >= 0;
}

private static bool DateTimeOfDayComparison(DateTime timeToCompareTo, DateTime created)
{
    //We are interested to compare up to the seconds, we are not interested in milliseconds
    return TimeSpan.Compare(StripMilliseconds(timeToCompareTo).TimeOfDay, StripMilliseconds(created).TimeOfDay) >= 0;
}

private static bool AbsoluteSecondsComparison(DateTime timeToCompareTo, DateTime created)
{
    return GetTotalSeconds(timeToCompareTo, created) < MaxTimeInSecondsTokenIsAlive;
}

private static DateTime StripMilliseconds(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return dateTime.AddTicks(-(dateTime.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond));
}

private static double GetTotalSeconds(DateTime timeToCompareTo, DateTime created)
{
    return (timeToCompareTo - created).Duration().TotalSeconds;
}
```

The `Created` property is set when the object is created and it will always be the timestamp of the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naming:

Method names should contain a verb and describe exactly what they are doing. For example, look at `DateComparison`. That sounds more like a type name to me, and I have no idea what the method will do by its name alone.

`StripMilliseconds` and `GetTotalSeconds` are much better.

---

I'd suggest this is as an alternate solution:

```
public static class TokenValidator
{
    private const int aliveDurationMinutes = 15;

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the token is still alive with a 1-second tolerance.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool CheckTokenAlive(DateTime created, DateTime timeToCompare)
    {
        TimeSpan elapsedTime = timeToCompare - created;

        return (elapsedTime.TotalSeconds > -1 && elapsedTime.TotalSeconds < 0) // up to 1 second before
               || (elapsedTime.TotalSeconds >= 0 && Math.Floor(elapsedTime.TotalSeconds) <= aliveDurationMinutes * 60); // up to 15 minutes later
    }
}
```

I use Math.Floor on the TotalSeconds to add the 1-second tolerance. You can be 0.9999 of a second over and still evaluate as true. You could have done a strictly less than with `((aliveDurationMinutes * 60) + 1)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

#### Benefit from short circuit behavior

In an expression like `a() && b() && ...`, when `a()` is `false`, then the rest of the expression will not need to be evaluated, because we can already know that the value of the entire expression will be `false`. Btw the same is true in `a() || b() || ...` when `a()` is `true`. This is called short circuit evaluation of conditional expressions and it's good to benefit from it when possible.

If you write `x = a(); y = b();` and then use `x && y && ...` then you don't benefit from short circuit evaluation, because `b()` has already been computed by the time the conditional expression is reached.

#### Naming

It's very difficult to understand what the code does, because of the names of methods and variables. For example, the word "comparison" is a noun, so it's not intuitive what will be the return value from that. Then I see the return type is boolean, but then when will it be true or false? Consider as an alternative `isBefore`. This name naturally implies boolean type, and that the value will be true if the first parameter date is before the second.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like all the private static methods. In my mind, you should create new methods in these cases:

1. Follow the Single Responsibility Principle
2. Make Code more readable (Long method)
3. Self-Document your code (the name of the method is a self-documentation)
4. Split out logic that needs to be overridden in lower classes (which you can't do with a static method)

Personally, I don't see a benefit to splitting out these particular methods, and I think they actually make the code harder to read. In this case, I would prefer the logic in one single method.

Also, I would find a way to make an adjustable threshold for the time that you allow to be alive. I like @RobH's const int of 15 minutes better than my static Timespans, but I will stick with them for this answer. I made the first one 15 minutes, 1 second. I made the second one -1 seconds. This is to handle the 1 second tolerance you mentioned.

```
private static TimeSpan MAX_ALLOWED_DIFF = new TimeSpan(0,15,1);
private static TimeSpan MIN_ALLOWED_DIFF = new TimeSpan(0,0,-1);

public bool IsTokenAlive(DateTime timeToCompareTo, DateTime created)
{
    TimeSpan diff = (created - timeToCompareTo);
    diff = diff - new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,diff.Milliseconds);

    return diff < MAX_ALLOWED_DIFF && diff > MIN_ALLOWED_DIFF;
}
```

Also, for those who are saying this doesn't pass all the tests, here is the linqpad script I used to test. If I messed something up when I copied the tests, please let me know.

```
void Main()
{
    IsTokenAlive(Parse("01/01/2017 15:00:00"), Parse("01/01/2017 15:15:00")).Dump(); //true
    IsTokenAlive(Parse("01/01/2017 15:00:00"), Parse("01/01/2017 15:00:00")).Dump(); //true
    IsTokenAlive(Parse("01/01/2017 15:00:00"), Parse("01/01/2017 15:16:00")).Dump(); //false
    IsTokenAlive(Parse("01/01/2017 15:00:00"), Parse("01/01/2017 14:59:59")).Dump(); //false
    IsTokenAlive(Parse("01/01/2017 15:00:0"), Parse("01/01/2017 15:14:59")).Dump(); //true
    IsTokenAlive(Parse("01/01/2017 15:00:00"), Parse("01/01/2017 15:16:01")).Dump(); //false
    IsTokenAlive(Parse("2017-01-01T15:00:00.0000001"), Parse("2017-01-01T15:15:00.0000002")).Dump(); //true
    IsTokenAlive(Parse("2017-01-01T15:15:00.5170000"), Parse("2017-01-01T15:15:00.4537587")).Dump(); //true
    IsTokenAlive(Parse("2017-01-01 15:00:00"), Parse("2017-12-31 15:00:00")).Dump(); //false
    IsTokenAlive(Parse("2018-05-06T13:30:43.2200000"), Parse("2018-05-06T13:30:42.9978916")).Dump(); //true

}

private DateTime Parse(string s)
{
    DateTime result = new DateTime();
    DateTime.TryParse(s, out result);
    return result;
}

// Define other methods and classes here

private static TimeSpan MAX_ALLOWED_DIFF = new TimeSpan(0,15,1);
private static TimeSpan MIN_ALLOWED_DIFF = new TimeSpan(0,0,-1);

public bool IsTokenAlive(DateTime timeToCompareTo, DateTime created)
{
    TimeSpan diff = (created - timeToCompareTo);
    diff = diff - new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,diff.Milliseconds);

    return diff < MAX_ALLOWED_DIFF && diff > MIN_ALLOWED_DIFF;
}
```

Comment: @user1304444, your solution fails on 4 out 10 test cases. Specifically test cases with ids 1, 4, 5 and 7